# How I put \sqrt in arial with unicode-math?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I need to write an document with Arial. And have some math.

I almost do this in entire document with this:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \setmathsfont(Digits)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
    \setmathsfont(Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
    \setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}

    \usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Arial}

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \sqrt{a+b}
    \]

    \[
    \int_{a}^{b}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

But the square root is broken, and the integral symbol is very small.

What can I do?

I found another package. This package provides math symbols for Myriad Pro, a sans serif font from Adobe. The final code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}

\usepackage{mdsymbol}
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide a full MWE example, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Why you have to use Arial font? LaTeX's native sans serif isnt't good enough for you?

Comment: @Crowley it's an requirement from my university

Comment: Do they require you to use Arial math symbols also ? I was not aware a full math font for Arial existed. If not, you could always use a font that matches Arial nicely just for math.

Comment: @JoãoApel Your university can not possibly require you to do that. There is no Arial math font. Use stix or combra math or some other unicode math font then (if you must) use \mathsf{...} so the letters are in sans serif.

Comment: @ach They don't require the symbol. But since i've learnt a little bit of typography, i see that symbol and want to turn it in Arial too, it's like bad kerning. Thanks

Comment: @JoãoApel opentype math fonts have to have a _lot_ of extra structure detailing how to extend characters and join rules to sqrt signs and stuff, That is why there are relatively few math fonts, and making one based on Arial would be a lot of work.

Comment: @JoãoApel: I thought so. But Do they recognize that you are not using Arial but some other Sans serif? I had plenty requirements to "write it with Times New Roman" when they were satisfied with any serif font... Too many people use "Arial" and "Times" as synonymes for sans serif and serif font types.

Answer (score 5):

There is no arial math font, so you need to use another font. (The university can not require the use of a font that does not exist),

Answer (score 2):

This works, but of course the integral and the square root symbols are not Arial. You may have also other problems, because Arial hasn't the math features requested for math fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
\setmathsfont(Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}

\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Arial}
\setmathfont[range={\sqrt,\int}]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{a+b}
\]

\[
\int_{a}^{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]